# Call threads before print yet print executes before threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

It's been a year or so since I played with `pthreads` from an OS class and I've been trying to get back into it just for fun. Below is the code for my simple threading exercise that I'm running through from an [online source](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html). My concern is that the tutorial says that the output should be:

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: 0
pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: 0
```

which makes sense to me. But I'm getting

```
pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: 0
pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: 0
Thread 1
Thread 2
```

**pthread1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main()
{
     pthread_t thread1, thread2;
     const char *message1 = "Thread 1";
     const char *message2 = "Thread 2";
     int  iret1, iret2;

     iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);

     if(iret1)
     {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret1);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

     if(iret2)
     {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret2);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     printf("pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
     printf("pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);


     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
     char *message;
     message = (char *) ptr;
     printf("%s \n", message);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your tutorial is wrong. Messages can appear in either order, or even interspersed.

Comment: The new thread may, but does not always, begin running before pthread_create() returns.  
So you may get control back in main() before each thread starts, or after. This unpredictability means that the display statements could appear in a different order to the textbook answer.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  1) there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function:  `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Note that both have return type of `int` 2) the `main()` function is missing the final closing brace '}', 3) the function: `print_message_function()` has a return type of `void*` but is missing that actual `return` statement.

Comment: When executing a program with multiple threads, there is no guarantee as to which thread will be executed and in what order.

Comment: the function: `print_message_function()` should be exited via: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called race condition.

It may possible that, After thread1 creation, scheduler schedules thread1 function1 first then it may possible that thread function execute first and then your main() prints comes.

On my system when i run your program.

```
jeegar@jeegarp:~$ ./a.out 
pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: 0
pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: 0
Thread 2 
Thread 1 
jeegar@jeegarp:~$ ./a.out 
pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: 0
pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: 0
Thread 1 
Thread 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a close look at the tutorial. Seems to me there is a mistake: code and its result just don't match (code is about return code from **pthread_create** and print out is about thread return code, which is not accessible because calls to **pthread_join** is done with **NULL** as second parameter as well as **print_message_function** lack of returning anything sensible)

Try **sleep(0);** before **if(iret2)** for fun...

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution depends on OS scheduling algorithm.Hence, any one either of thread or the function creating thread can get scheduled(depending on the OS scheduling algo).